# How to make SOAP calls in magento2.I am using a third party API service

Tags: soap, soap-api

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient(
    "https://sandbox.ws-idu.tracesmart.co.uk/v5.6/?wsdl"
);

    // Set up Classes ready for populating specific wsdl fields
    $params = new stdClass;
    $params->Login = new stdClass;
    $params->IDU = new stdClass;
    $params->Person = new stdClass;
    $params->Services = new stdClass;

    
    // Enter the Username and password associated with your account
    $params->Login->username                        = '';
    $params->Login->password                        = '';
    
    // Reference is optional/mandatory based on user settings
    $params->IDU->Reference                         = '';
    // ID and IKey should be passed to continue a previous search
    $params->IDU->ID                                = '';
    $params->IDU->IKey                              = '';
    // $params->IDU->Scorecard                         = 'IDU Default';
    $params->IDU->Scorecard                         = 'Identity Verification default';
    $params->IDU->equifaxUsername                   = '';
    $params->IDU->GlobalTransactionId                   = '';

    
    // Subject details
    $params->Person->forename                       = 'HEATHER';
    $params->Person->middle                         = 'JANE';
    $params->Person->surname                        = 'RUSSELL';
    $params->Person->gender                         = 'F';
    $params->Person->dob                            = '1946-04-21';
    
    $params->Person->address1                       = '201';
    $params->Person->address2                       = 'Julius Road';
    $params->Person->address3                       = 'Bristol';
    $params->Person->address4                       = '';
    $params->Person->address5                       = '';
    $params->Person->address6                       = '';
    $params->Person->postcode                       = 'BS7 8EU';
    
    
    
    // var_dump($params);
    // $results = $client->GlobalTransactionId = '1';
    $results = $client->IDUProcess($params);
    
    var_dump($results);
    var_dump($results->Summary);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try like below:

> Copy your XML in etc/wsdl/WebServices.xml

```
 $wsdlPath = $this->_moduleReader->getModuleDir('etc', 'Vendor_Module') . '/'. 'wsdl';
 // \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader as Modulereader
 $wsdl = $wsdlPath . '/' . 'WebServices.xml';
 $client = new \SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1)); 
 $result = $client->yourMethod($params);
 var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Hi anonymous,
I didn't got your point.Can you please specify more how we can achieve this.